# Remove id attribute from stylesheet link

Tags: css

Right now I'm serving up my own custom stylesheet.

```
// register main stylesheet
wp_register_style( 'custom-stylesheet', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/css/main.css', array(), '', 'all' );
```

It outputs:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='custom-stylesheet-css'  href='http://localhost/wp-content/themes/custom-theme/library/css/main.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Is there a way to remove the `id='custom-stylesheet-css` part of that stylesheet?? Is there a reason that they add an `id` attribute?

Comment: Honestly, and respectfully, that `id` is probably not necessary, but nor is it important enough to bother with. Can you tell me why this is an issue?

Comment: I would like to understand why they include it there. Wasn't sure if there was an easy way to do it. I'm just a neat freak ;)

Comment: @s_ha_dum mod_pagespeed is not able to combine css files if they have defined different ids. https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2011/10/wordpress-and-mod_pagespeed-why-combine_css-does-not-work/

Answer (score 3):

You can filter `style_loader_tag`. You get the HTML element and the handle as arguments.

Example

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', function( $html, $handle ) {

    if ( 'custom-stylesheet' !== $handle )
        return $html;

    return str_replace( " id='$handle-css'", '', $html );
}, 10, 2 );
```

But really, I would not waste processing time for that. The `id` exists to make the element easier to access per JavaScript. It doesn’t hurt if you don’t need it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your functions.php:

```
add_filter("style_loader_tag", function($tag){
    return str_replace("id='custom-stylesheet-css' " ,'',  $tag);
});
```

Nice and simple.

Comment: How is your answer different than mine, except that it changes `id` attributes without knowing if they’re needed?